# Git - files from committed and pushed changes need to be uncommitted

Tags: git, github

On a separate branch as a pull request I have committed and pushed some system and project environment files. They cause huge issues for other developers because they are my system files interfering with their system files. How can I remove those files from that PR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you modified the files on my-branch~3:

```
git checkout my-branch~3
git checkout HEAD~1 -- some-file.txt some-file2.txt
git commit --amend --no-edit # amend revision, those files will be as they were on previous revision
git cherry-pick my-branch~3..my-branch # rewrite remaining history of branch
# check the branch to make sure everything is of
# if it is... continue with the recipe
git branch -f my-branch #move branch pointer to new rewritten branch
git checkout my-branch
git push --force origin my-branch # adjust name of branch and remote
```

Comment: There are same system files on the master branch. The idea is not to overwrite masters system files. By deleting these files from my PR, I am hoping the masters system files will not be deleted. Do you think they will be deleted after merging my PR?

Comment: Let me see if I get it straight. So, you created a feature branch from master. The files do exist on master. Then you delete them from your feature branch? If that's correct, then when your branch is merged into master, they will be deleted from master. And if they exist on master, then the question would be: why do you want to delete them from your feature request _while_ wanting to keep them untouched on master?

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on... then the recipe has to be adjusted.... they are not to be deleted. Hold on

Comment: The contents of those files were changed by my environment. I don't want those changes in the master

Comment: Oh... and if those files are included in the project and you want them to be modified locally and not have git asking you about those modified files, .gitignore won't hold water. You should consider using `git update-index --assume-unchanged` for those files. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

Comment: You are very helpful, Thank you for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181691/discussion-between-ziyo-and-eftshift0).